# PHP importing to flash quiz

Tags: php, arrays, string, actionscript-3, flash

first time posting, hopefully this will be helpful to others too. I've found a few posts on this topic but it appears I'm having quite a specific problem.

**This is my output in PHP**

> questions=The ‘Sea Swallow’ is an alternative name for which bird?/In which sport would you see a ‘Western Roll’?/Who is better known as ‘Herbert Khaury’?/'Diet' is the parliament of which country?/What is the real first name of Coco Chanel?/'The Aztecs' were natives of which country?/What was invented by‘O.A. North’ in 1869?/King Zog was the ruler of which country?&answers=Seagull/Penguin/Tern/Cormorant&correct=0/0/1/0&

**And this is my AS3 code**

```
     var         request:URLRequest = new             
URLRequest("http://localhost:8888/Quiz/questions.php");
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

            var loader2:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loader2.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            loader2.load(request);


            function completeHandler(event:Event) :void{

            var questions1 = event.target.data.questions1;

            // dynamic text box called username

            questionbox.question.text=event.target.data.questionbox.question.text;

            }

            var questions:String;
            var questionsArray:Array=questions.split("/");
```

I'm trying to get the question to appear in a dynamic text box,but am receiving the error code #2007 Parameter text must be non-null.

I'm effectively trying to turn my string into an array.

Can anybody see the problem here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

EDIT:

**This is my PHP code**

```
<?php
//functions

function get_id($column, $table)
{
 $sql    = mysql_query("select $column FROM $table") ;
 while ($row    =mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
  return $row["ID"];
 }
}

function getquestions($id)
{
 $sql    =mysql_query("select text FROM questions WHERE quiz_ID =$id ");
 $questions   = array();
 while($row   = mysql_fetch_row($sql))
 {
  $questions[] = $row[0];
 }
 return $questions;
}

function getanswers($id)
{
 $sql    = mysql_query("select answer FROM answers WHERE question_ID= $id ");
 $answers = array();
 while($row    =mysql_fetch_row($sql))
 {

  $answers[] = $row[0]; 
 }

 return $answers;
}

function getcorrect($id)
{
 $sql    = mysql_query("SELECT correct FROM answers WHERE question_ID= $id ");
 $correct   =array();
 while($row    =mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
 {
  $correct[]    =$row["correct"]; 
 }
   return $correct;
}


//Connect to Database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","dinita","3nd3m0luk");

if(!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

else
{

 // SELECT DATABASE
mysql_select_db("quizCreation", $con);

// Create an array of data from database


$quizid    = get_id("ID","quizName");
$questionid    = get_id("ID", "questions");
$ques   = implode("/",getquestions($quizid));
$ans    =implode("/",getanswers($questionid)); 
$cor    =implode("/", getcorrect($questionid));


echo htmlentities( "questions"."=". $ques."&");
echo htmlentities("answers"."=".$ans."&");
echo htmlentities("correct"."=".$cor."&");

}

mysql_close($con); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the output of your php code, then if you have to visualize it in the textield, you should change it like this:

```
        var questions:String = event.target.data.questions;
        questionbox.question.text=questions;
```

And if you want to convert the String as an Array, then do like this:

```
       var questionsArray:Array=questions.split("/");
```

Comment: questions1 was the remnants of a previous attempt sorry! Still getting the same error though.

When I test the flash I get an TypeError Error: #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference
and
ReferenceError Error #1069: Property questions not found on String and there is no default value

At the moment I'm just focusing on trying to get the questions to appear in flash before I try to get the questions working too, baby steps for me atm! 

Thanks for the reply

Comment: please comment the last two lines of your code and tell me which and where you have errors

Comment: Edited my AS to what you mentioned above and am now getting just one error which is 1120: Access of undefined property questions

That is occuring on  var questionsArray:Array=questions.split("/");

so is this a problem in my php?

Comment: No, it's not a problem of your PHP. The problem you have is that you are trying to split a string that is undefined, because the variable questions is defined in the scope of the function completeHandler. If you try to move that line INSIDE the function, you'll see it working

Comment: So I moved the var questions:String into the function completeHandler (my bad for not having it in there in the first place) but still get the same error messages mentioned in my first comment. Is there any more information I can give you to be more helpful? Appreciate your feedback

Comment: Change URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT to URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES

Comment: Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
 at flash.net::URLVariables()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES.toUpperCase()

Comment: if it's going to work I'm going to include everything in the answer

Comment: Hi Sr.Richie just wanted to update you with what the problem was. We were hosting the PHP on a local server, Flash didn't seem to like that at all. Your code was actually working pretty much spot on! Thanks again for the help